# Ошибка при наследовании: не содержит конструктор, который принимает 0 аргументов

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование

Одна из моих ранних лаб:

```
        class MainHouse
        {
                protected float width;
                protected float height;
                protected float length;

                protected int floors;
                protected int apartment;
                protected int tenants;

                public MainHouse()
                {
                    width = 0;
                    height = 0;
                    length = 0;

                    floors = 0;
                    apartment = 0;
                    tenants = 0;
                }
                ...
    }

    class Type2 : MainHouse
    {
        protected string st;

        public Type2(float a1, float a2, float a3, string c1)
        {
            this.width = a1;
            this.height = a2;
            this.length = a3;

            this.st = c1;
        }
        ...
    }
```

Тут всё нормально работает.
Почему тут ошибка: BasicRoomNS.BasicRoom не содержит конструктор, который принимает 0 аргументов?

```
    class BasicRoom
    {
        protected int numberOfFurniture;
        protected int numberOfRooms;
        protected int apartmentNumber;
        protected int cost;
        protected bool wifi;

        public BasicRoom(int a, int b, int c, bool w) : base()
        {
            numberOfFurniture = a;
            numberOfRooms = b;
            apartmentNumber = c;
            wifi = w;
        }


    class PremiumRoom : BasicRoom
    {
        protected bool bar;
        public PremiumRoom(bool ba, int a, int b, int c, bool w) // Тут ошибка
        {
            this.numberOfFurniture = a;
            this.numberOfRooms = b;
            this.apartmentNumber = c;
            this.wifi = w;

            bar = ba;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Для чего вообще конструктор с 0 аргументами? У меня же их 5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну собственно все очевидно - базовый тип BasicRoom, от которого наследуется PremiumRoom, не содержит конструктора по умолчанию, потому что вы его не определили. Обычно он создается автоматически (а потому и называется конструктором по умолчанию), но если вы создаете какой-то другой конструктор, то этого не происходит. Однако поскольку PremiumRoom - наследник класса BacicRoom, для его корректной инициализации в нем должна происходить инициализация базового класса, чего вы в данном случае не делаете.Чтобы исправить ошибку вам нужно либо определить конструктор по умолчанию у базового класса, либо вызвать имеющийся конструктор например таким образом:

```
public PremiumRoom(bool ba, int a, int b, int c, bool w) : base(a, b, c, w)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Почему тут ошибка: BasicRoomNS.BasicRoom не содержит конструктор, который принимает 0 аргументов?

Тут же всё написано. Ты не вызываешь явно базовый конструктор с параметрами, поэтому компилятор пытается неявно вызвать конструктор без параметров, который не был сгенерирован, поскольку есть конструктор с параметрами.